# redirect the user to dynamic page after they allowed the facebook app?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I have images on my website that the user needs to allow the Facebook application in order to view them. So when the user click on the image (thumbnail) it should talk him to the image page and check if he allowed the application. So how do I redirect the user to the user to that specific image page after allowing the Facebook application. something like this:

```
header('Location: image_page.php');
```

I tried this it is taking him to the allow page on facebook again. I tried to change the -1 but I got the same problem:

```
header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to populate the URL of the referring page as the `redirect_uri` you specify when you call the Facebook auth dialog.

Answer (score 0):

you should specific the image page when redirect the user to facebook to allow your application.

here is the url to redirect user to Facebook auth:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE
```

you should replace `YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE` with your image page url

Comment: I am using `$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();`